# GET parameter PHP

Tags: php, html

I have HTML/PHP website (HTML code inside my .php)

I am using the $_GET["name"] method so that I can write the name of my guest in the link I send
(for exemple : mywebsite.com/index.php?name=Mike). Here's the code I use :

```
<p class="guest_info"> 
        <?php echo " " . $_GET["name"]; ?> 
        <img alt="account_avatar" src="./index_files/avatar.svg">
        </p>
```

Now, I would like this name to be implemented to the differents pages. My current problem is that if I give the link and after click on another page of my website, the ["name"] is not saved. I Would like to save the name used in the first given URL while navigating, and if I change the name in the link, that it automaticaly changes the pages aswell.

Thanks for helping

Comment: *"I am using the $_GET["email"] method so that I can write the name of my guest in the link I send (for exemple : mywebsite.com/index.php?name=Mike). Here's the code I use :"* - So which one is it, `$_GET["email"]` or `$_GET["name"]`? In either case, the question is too broad.

Comment: $_GET["name"] :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [PHP session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or a [browser cookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

Using the session route, at the beginning of your page, be sure to add `session_start()`.

Then you can store the value as a session value.

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $_GET) && !array_key_exists('name', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Now, anywhere after that code, you can use `$_SESSION['name']` to access the value as long as the session persists.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `$_GET['name']` to persist from page to page, you need to keep passing it in the URL query string. For example, something like this: `<a href="index.php?name=<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>">Link</a>`

Comment: This would require every single link the user accesses to have the `$_GET` parameter set.